# MySql table into JSON format

Tags: mysql, json, migration

I would like to convert like 100 tables from MySql to MongoDb

 So I think that the easiest way will be to import the data as JSON

 Any generic query to convert MySql data to JSON format without using PHP /ruby/Python?

```
SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('{"CompanyId":', company_id),"}")  AS JSON FROM company;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @schema = 'test_db';
SET @table = 'test';

SELECT CONCAT(
  'SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ', QUOTE(','), ' FROM CONCAT(', QUOTE('{'), ',', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ',', 
  QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(':'), ',', QUOTE('"'), ',', COLUMN_NAME, ',', 
  QUOTE('"'),',', QUOTE(',')),
  ')), ''}'') FROM ', @table
)
INTO @qry FROM 
  (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema AND TABLE_NAME = @table) t;

SELECT @qry;
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Above query generates table data in JSON format. Using the query you can prepare a stored procedure taking database and table names as input parameters and populate your data. If you want to exclude some of the columns in a table, just modify the query which selects data from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database like `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema AND TABLE_NAME = @table AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (**columns to exclude**)`.

Comment: work like a charm!
                  changed 6 line to add IFNULL check:                                    QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(':'), ',', QUOTE('"'), ',IFNULL(', COLUMN_NAME, ',""),',

Answer (score 2):

I extended oardic's answer to create a mysql procedure to generate json from table name along with null check. Here key is set to value `null` instead of empty string.

```
create procedure createJSON (IN tabelSchema varchar(255), IN tableName varchar(255), IN whereCondition varchar(255), OUT outJson longtext)
BEGIN
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS RowJson;
  SELECT CONCAT(
      'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE RowJson AS SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ', QUOTE(','), ' FROM CONCAT(', QUOTE('{'), ',',
      GROUP_CONCAT(QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(COLUMN_NAME), ',',
                   QUOTE('"'), ',', QUOTE(':'), ',', 'IF(ISNULL(', COLUMN_NAME, '), "null", CONCAT(',QUOTE('"'),",", COLUMN_NAME, ",", QUOTE('"'),')),',
                   QUOTE(',')),
      ')), ''}'') as json FROM ', tableName, ' WHERE ', whereCondition
  )
  INTO @qry FROM
    (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = tabelSchema AND TABLE_NAME = tableName) t;

  PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
  EXECUTE stmt;

  SELECT json into outJson FROM RowJson;
END;
```

Comment: please let me know how I will call these procedure

Comment: call createJSON('schema_name', 'table_name', outJson)