# Is there a simple way to import MySQL table structures and eventually the data into Firebase?

Tags: mysql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I read about exporting it to json, but how do I go about taking the table structures and exporting them to json and the follow-up question is how do i do so for the data in the tables as well!?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18916172/migrating-data-into-firebase-from-mysql

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to import mysql table structure in Firebase console. You'll need to convert your [mysql data into JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836710/mysql-table-into-json-format) then upload it. Also, if you're uploading more than 250MB JSON file then use this [Firebase-Import](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-import) utility tool. Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess the question becomes how do I convert my MySQL data into JSON format? Is there a utility that can do that, or do  need to code something myself?

Comment: See Frank van Puffelen's comment.